# Issue creating a module project in java 9

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

I am trying to set up a basic java project using java commands in windows 10 following a tutorial.
The files are

`C:\Users\Talon\Desktop\java intellij\01j9\src\com.me.mymodule\module-info.java
C:\Users\Talon\Desktop\java intellij\01j9\src\com.me.mymodule\com\me\mymodule\Main.java`

and an empty folder `C:\Users\Talon\Desktop\java intellij\01j9\mods\com.me.mymodule`.

module-info.java

```
module com.me.mymodule {}
```

Main.java

```
package com.me.mymodule;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World from Module");
    }
}
```

After getting 'cd' into `C:\Users\Talon\Desktop\java intellij\01j9>`
the command i'm supposed to enter is

```
javac -d mods/com.me.mymodule \ src/com.me.mymodule/module-info.java \ src/com.me.mymodule/com/me/mymodule/Main.java
```

but it's written for machintosh os, so in windows i tried

```
javac -d mods/com.me.mymodule;src/com.me.mymodule/module-info.java;src/com.me/mymodule/com/me/mymodule/Main.java
```

and

```
javac -d mods\com.me.mymodule;src\com.me.mymodule\module-info.java;src\com.me\mymodule\com\me\mymodule\Main.java
```

In both i have **javac: no source files**. Are the path wrong or i am supposed to enter a different command ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm) describes the JDK9's `javac` command-line tool syntax.

Your command should be

```
javac -d mods\com.me.mymodule src\com.me.mymodule\module-info.java src\com.me\mymodule\com\me\mymodule\Main.java
```

Where both the `module-info.java` and `Main.java` are "sourceFiles", while `-d mods\com.me.mymodule` specifies a target directory.